# update Seaborn FacetGrid with a slider widget

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to dynamically update a figure created using FacetGrid. I made a custom plotting function (plot_heatmap_w_scatter), in which I want to add a correction factor to the scatter function inside. Without the slider it works alright, but when I change the value of the slider (triggering the update function), apparently it doesn't clear the axes of the FacetGrid, showing the same plots.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

def plot_heatmap_w_scatter(data, **kws):
  correction = kws['correction']
  tmp = data.pivot(index='k', columns='x0', values='pdf')
  sns.heatmap(tmp)
  plt.scatter(another_x - correction, another_y)

f = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='context')
f.map_dataframe(plot_heatmap_w_scatter)

plt.figure(f.fig.number)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

ax_slider = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
slider = Slider(label='correction',
                ax=ax_slider, valmin=0, valmax=20)

def update(val):
  for ax in f.axes.flat:
     ax.clear()
  f.map_dataframe(plot_heatmap_w_scatter, kws={'correction': val})

slider.on_changed(update)

f.fig.show()
```

I've tried with `plt.clf()` instead of `ax.clear()`, and it erases the full figure, but it doesn't draw anything after (even after calling map_dataframe again in update). Any suggestions on debugging or how to achieve an update of the FacetGrid are welcome. I'm using matplotlib.widgets into ipython (not JupyterLab/notebooks), but would consider changing to JupyterLab if it's easier to achieve the update.